# Find gaps in a List of object with Start/End dates

Tags: c#

I have a list of objects which hold a Start and End date for a rate a person charged.

```
public class ProjectResourceCostDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ProjectResourceId { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
        public decimal Cost { get; set; }
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a project start and end date. So what I need to do is return a List<> of 'Gaps', where there is no rate set.

So, if I have a Project Start date as "01-JAN-2013" and an end on "31-DEC-2013", they are my inputs.

I need to go through the List, and output List of Start/End dates where there is no payment rates.

So, if my list of objects have:

Start=05-JAN-2013
End=01-OCT-2013

Start=15-OCT-2013
End=25-DEC-2013

Then, I'd need to return:
01-JAN-2013
04-JAN-2013

02-OCT-2013
14-OCT-2013

26-DEC-2013
31-DEC-2013

Those are period where I can't determine a rate.

It's to be done in C# code. I'm using Entity Framework, so MAYBE another option would be a View in SQL Server, which I can make use of ... I do have a Calendar table with all dates... But first prize would be if someone had a routine that I could use in code to work out these period.

Comment: Try this library: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET

Answer (score 0):

You can order the list of inputs by date (start date, for example) and then iterate through it by adding the dates to a new list every time the target condition is met (i.e., Cost = 0). Here you have a sample code writing all the relevant dates into `gapsList`:

```
List<ProjectResourceCostDto> testList = new List<ProjectResourceCostDto>();
testList.Add(new ProjectResourceCostDto{Id = 1, ProjectResourceId = 1, StartDate = new DateTime(2001,2,1), EndDate = new DateTime(2002, 1,1), Cost = 1111, Deleted = false});
testList.Add(new ProjectResourceCostDto{Id = 2, ProjectResourceId = 2, StartDate = new DateTime(2003,1,1), EndDate = new DateTime(2004, 1,1), Cost = 0, Deleted = false});
testList.Add(new ProjectResourceCostDto { Id = 3, ProjectResourceId = 3, StartDate = new DateTime(2005, 1, 1), EndDate = new DateTime(2006, 1, 1), Cost = 999, Deleted = false });

DateTime firstDate = new DateTime(2001, 1, 1);
DateTime lastDate = new DateTime(2006, 2, 1);
List<DateTime> gapsList = new List<DateTime>();
gapsList.Add(firstDate);
testList = testList.OrderBy(n => n.StartDate).ToList();
foreach(ProjectResourceCostDto item in testList)
{
    if (item.Cost == 0)
    {
        gapsList.Add(item.StartDate);
        gapsList.Add((DateTime)item.EndDate);
    }
}
gapsList.Add(lastDate);
```